# Adding context to Javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have this code which reads the contents of a file, expects it to be json, parses it and prints out the result:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

const printFile = (file) => fs.readFileAsync(file, "utf-8")
  .then((jsonHopefully) => console.log(JSON.parse(jsonHopefully)))
  ;

printFile("/tmp/x")
  .catch( (error) => console.log(error));
```

If the file does not contain json, but contains the text Hello, I get this error printed:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token H]
```

I want extra context in this error message, specifically I want the file name.  I decided to do this:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

const printFile = (file) => fs.readFileAsync(file, "utf-8")
  .then((jsonHopefully) => console.log(JSON.parse(jsonHopefully)))
  .catch( error => {
    error.message = "File " + file + ": " + error.message;
    throw error;
  })
  ;

printFile("/tmp/x")
  .catch( (error) => console.log(error));
```

And then I get this error message:

```
[SyntaxError: File /tmp/x: Unexpected token H]
```

Which is what I want.

But I just made up this approach and I am not an expert javascript programmer ( yet :) ).  So my question is: is this the right way to add context to an Error?

Comment: This might be a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly throw the error

```
 throw Error("Bogus error to test error, ${someParameters} are observed.")
```

I would not edit the error message directly